# Waterline ORM drops columns and converts to myisam for mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, waterline

I am completely new to NodeJS.  I'm trying to build an express app (not a sails app) with a mysql database.  I have a weird issue where the Waterline ORM is unexpectedly dropping a column on one of my mysql database tables and converting the engine type from innodb to myisam.  Here's my code to reproduce the error.

First, I create a couple of mysql database tables via mysql terminal:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `c` (
  `c_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `d` (
  `d_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`d_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `d_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `c`(`c_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I have a node js file called `start.js` that has this code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app  = express();
var Waterline = require("waterline");

var orm = new Waterline();


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WATERLINE CONFIG
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Require any waterline compatible adapters here
var diskAdapter = require('sails-disk'),
    mysqlAdapter = require('sails-mysql');


// Build A Config Object
var config = {

  // Setup Adapters
  // Creates named adapters that have have been required
  adapters: {
    'default': diskAdapter,
    disk: diskAdapter,
    mysql: mysqlAdapter
  },

  // Build Connections Config
  // Setup connections using the named adapter configs
  connections: {
    myLocalDisk: {
      adapter: 'disk'
    },

    myLocalMySql: {
      adapter: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'waterdb',
      user: 'mysqluser',
      password: 'mybordingpassword'
    }
  }

};


var D = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  tableName: 'd',
  identity: 'd',
  connection: 'myLocalMySql',

  attributes: {
    d_id: {type:'integer'},
    name: {type:'string'}
  }
});

orm.loadCollection(D);

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Running Server on Port 3000.");

    orm.initialize(config, function(err, models) {
      if(err) throw err;
      app.models = models.collections;
      app.connections = models.connections;

      app.models.d.find().exec(function(err,models){

        if(err) return res.json({ err: err }, 500);
        console.log(models);

      });


    });

});
```

Next I just run this app from bash by executing `node start.js`.  Then when I go into mysql and do a `show create table d`, I see the results:

```
CREATE TABLE `d` (
  `d_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Why did my node js code drop the column c_id and change the engine to myisam for the table `d`?

Answer (score 2):

The column is being dropped because by default waterline uses `migrate: 'alter'` which drops all tables, recreates them and re-adds the data. To prevent the existing data from being touched I suggest to use `migrate: 'create'` which only adds new tables/columns. To prevent data and schema from being changed use `migrate: 'safe'` (which is the recommended setting for production). More about this on the [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/5cc4b64207a8cb8e81c53358c7d6024e26e02147/models/configuration.md#migrate) and on the [adapter interface specification](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/contributing/adapter-specification.md#auto-migration-strategies). BTW, this default should change in v0.11 to `'safe'`.

Regarding the engine, it's also changing due to the migration `'alter'` and I suspect `MyISAM` is the [sails-mysql](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) default for new tables.

Comment: thanks, i'll check things out soon, i also have a really closely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644736/waterline-orm-foreign-key-error